# Parasitic capacitance of high-speed comparator

Tags: oscillator, frequency, comparator, parasitic-capacitance

[image]

I simulated an [LM119](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm119) high-speed comparator and built one on a breadboard.

May I ask how to increase the frequency of the square wave produced by adjusting the resistor's values instead of reducing the capacitor C1?

This is because I encountered parasitic capacitance which keeps changing the fast square wave's frequency and I want to avoid that. I assume I would have to keep the capacitor value high, so the resistor values must be adjusted to increase the frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Reducing R5 increases the frequency.
- Increasing R2 increases the frequency.

You could also simulate that given that you already have a spice circuit.